# How can I sort and add a rank column within a multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this (`df3`)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "period": [1, 2, 3, 4] * 4,
    "cat1": ["A"] * 8 + ["B"] * 8,
    "cat2": (["X"] * 4 + ["Y"] * 4) * 2,
    "amount": [100, 200, 300, 400, 110, 210, 310, 410, 120, 220, 320, 420, 130, 230, 330, 430],
    "total": [1000] * 16
})
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.amount = df2.amount + 1
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

What I would like to do is

- Split into groups based on the values of `cat1`, `cat2`, and `period`.
- Filter to the rows with the max `amount` value within each of those groups.
- Sort the resulting dataframe on `amount` within the groups defined by `['cat1', 'cat2']` (not `period`).
- Add cumulative percentage column within each group defined by `['cat1', 'cat2']`. I.e., if there are 4 values within the group, then the highest value gets assigned `0.25`, the second highest value gets assigned `0.5`, etc.

I can do the first two parts with

```
df4 = df3.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'period']).agg({
    "amount": "max"
})
```

But now `df4` has a multiindex on `['cat1', 'cat2', 'period']` and I don't know how to sort within the groups defined by the multiindex, or how to add a cumulative count within those groups.

I'm fine with losing the multiindex (I'm just going to insert these data into a SQL table anyway) but I don't know how to do that either, if if it would be efficient to do so.

My desired result is

```
cat1 cat2 period  amount  rank  percentage
A    X    4          401     1        0.25
A    X    3          301     2        0.50
A    X    2          201     3        0.75
A    X    1          101     4        1.00
A    Y    4          411     1        0.25
A    Y    3          311     2        0.50
A    Y    2          211     3        0.75
B    X    4          421     4        1.00
B    X    3          321     1        0.25
B    X    2          221     2        0.50
B    X    1          121     3        0.75
A    Y    1          111     4        1.00
B    Y    4          431     1        0.25
B    Y    3          331     2        0.50
B    Y    2          231     3        0.75
B    Y    1          131     4        1.00
```

(I don't actually need the `rank` column, I just left it there for clarity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df4 = df3.groupby(['cat1', 'cat2', 'period']).agg({
    "amount": "max"
})
df4.reset_index(inplace=True)
df4 = df4.sort_values(by=['cat1','cat2','amount'],ascending=[True,True,False])
df4 = df4.assign(percentage=df4.groupby(['cat1','cat2'])['amount'].apply(lambda x: (x.notnull().cumsum()/x.size)))
print(df4)
```

Output:

```
   cat1 cat2  period  amount  percentage
3     A    X       4     401        0.25
2     A    X       3     301        0.50
1     A    X       2     201        0.75
0     A    X       1     101        1.00
7     A    Y       4     411        0.25
6     A    Y       3     311        0.50
5     A    Y       2     211        0.75
4     A    Y       1     111        1.00
11    B    X       4     421        0.25
10    B    X       3     321        0.50
9     B    X       2     221        0.75
8     B    X       1     121        1.00
15    B    Y       4     431        0.25
14    B    Y       3     331        0.50
13    B    Y       2     231        0.75
12    B    Y       1     131        1.00
```